# Prove that $f(x)=x^3$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ using partitions

Tags: analysis

Consider the function $f(x)=x^3$. Prove it is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ using partitions.

Comment: I would like to see it for this specific example.

Comment: It reduces to $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^3 = \frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ and that last sum has a nice closed form.